# Injecting messages/data into a Bubbletea application from within a for loop

Tags: go, terminal

I'm using [this](https://github.com/charmbracelet/bubbletea/blob/master/examples/send-msg/main.go) example Bubbletea application as the basis of a simple demo that listens for a stream of events from an HTTP service. The http listener runs in a `for` loop that currently just prints the events. e.g.

```
for {

        line, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            fmt.Printf("Error reading streamed bytes %v", err)
        }
        rb = append(rb, line...)
        err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(rb), &h)
        if err == nil {
            err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(h.HTTPBufferedTrace.Request.Body.AsString), &r)
            log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Status: [%s]\n", r.Request))
            
            p.Send(resultMsg{food: r.Request, duration: 0}) // trying to send to             Bubbletea queue here

}
```

I now want to inject/send the returned events to a Bubbletea TUI application i.e. `p.Send(resultMsg{food: r.Request, duration: 0})`.

However none of the HTTP events seemed to be received by the Bubbletree app.

I think my problem is due the the fact that the sender needs to be a go routine like in the example and probably lack of understand as to how go routes work. I've tried running my `for` loop in the go routine that simulates the activity but it still does not work.

```golang
package main

// A simple example that shows how to send messages to a Bubble Tea program
// from outside the program using Program.Send(Msg).

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/charmbracelet/bubbles/spinner"
    tea "github.com/charmbracelet/bubbletea"
    "github.com/charmbracelet/lipgloss"
)

var (
    spinnerStyle  = lipgloss.NewStyle().Foreground(lipgloss.Color("63"))
    helpStyle     = lipgloss.NewStyle().Foreground(lipgloss.Color("241")).Margin(1, 0)
    dotStyle      = helpStyle.Copy().UnsetMargins()
    durationStyle = dotStyle.Copy()
    appStyle      = lipgloss.NewStyle().Margin(1, 2, 0, 2)
)

type resultMsg struct {
    duration time.Duration
    food     string
}

func (r resultMsg) String() string {
    if r.duration == 0 {
        return dotStyle.Render(strings.Repeat(".", 30))
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf(" Ate %s %s", r.food,
        durationStyle.Render(r.duration.String()))
}

type model struct {
    spinner  spinner.Model
    results  []resultMsg
    quitting bool
}

func newModel() model {
    const numLastResults = 5
    s := spinner.New()
    s.Style = spinnerStyle
    return model{
        spinner: s,
        results: make([]resultMsg, numLastResults),
    }
}

func (m model) Init() tea.Cmd {
    return m.spinner.Tick
}

func (m model) Update(msg tea.Msg) (tea.Model, tea.Cmd) {
    switch msg := msg.(type) {
    case tea.KeyMsg:
        m.quitting = true
        return m, tea.Quit
    case resultMsg:
        m.results = append(m.results[1:], msg)
        return m, nil
    case spinner.TickMsg:
        var cmd tea.Cmd
        m.spinner, cmd = m.spinner.Update(msg)
        return m, cmd
    default:
        return m, nil
    }
}

func (m model) View() string {
    var s string

    if m.quitting {
        s += "That’s all for today!"
    } else {
        s += m.spinner.View() + " Eating food..."
    }

    s += "\n\n"

    for _, res := range m.results {
        s += res.String() + "\n"
    }

    if !m.quitting {
        s += helpStyle.Render("Press any key to exit")
    }

    if m.quitting {
        s += "\n"
    }

    return appStyle.Render(s)
}

func main() {
    p := tea.NewProgram(newModel())

    // Simulate activity
    go func() {
        for {
            pause := time.Duration(rand.Int63n(899)+100) * time.Millisecond // nolint:gosec
            time.Sleep(pause)

            // Send the Bubble Tea program a message from outside the
            // tea.Program. This will block until it is ready to receive
            // messages.
            p.Send(resultMsg{food: randomFood(), duration: pause})
        }
    }()

    if _, err := p.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error running program:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func randomFood() string {
    food := []string{
        "an apple", "a pear", "a gherkin", "a party gherkin",
        "a kohlrabi", "some spaghetti", "tacos", "a currywurst", "some curry",
        "a sandwich", "some peanut butter", "some cashews", "some ramen",
    }
    return food[rand.Intn(len(food))] // nolint:gosec
}
```